# My understanding of computer hardware architecture

Tags: voltage, current, flash, ram, ddr

[image]

Forgive my above crude diagram.

Assume the above is the hardware architecture for a computer/mobile phone or any device which hold a microprocessor.

Please let me know whether my understanding is correct or not, snd please correct if I am wrong.

1. The NOR flash has the boot code. I understand boot code is the starting stage of any device which needs to function. So, the boot code instructs the SSD to start the operating system from a selected starting point given in the boot code. So, this boot code is taken by the SSD and then transfers the entire operating system contents to the DDR4 RAM module for quick access by the CPU. NOR flash is a non-volatile memory, and RAM is a volatile memory.
2. SSD is where the operating system is stored. I am not sure of what other details or information are stored within an SSD other than the operating system. Please let me know what are the other information that are stored in SSD.
3. The CPU performs the calculations for any task. I have heard the multi-core CPU terms like quad core and octa-core.  What does an individual core block contain internally? I mean, what are the electronics or circuit blocks that are present inside each CPU core block? Please help me with this. I have googled but was not able to find the answer.
4. Suppose we download any document from the internet, does the document get stored in the SSD or within the NAND flash. I read that the NAND flash chips are used in USBs and used for high volume content storage. 2here does the downloaded content from the internet get stored? Is it stored the inside NAND flash or does it get stored in the SSD itself?

Please also let me know whether the directional arrows to each blocks in my above crude diagram are correct, and also let me know if I missed out any critical functions that each block will perform.

Comment: This is pretty confused and beyond the scope of SO and instead in the domain of traditional references.   To point out just a few of the issues,  SSD is today all but certainly made of NAND flash.  Some systems might use NAND in more loose form; few would have both.  Where web content gets cached is up to the OS, browser,  or even *user*... but then there's also swap...

Comment: Your question is too broad. Your diagram is certainly not generally applicable to "any device which holds a microprocessor". NOR flash may contain the boot code (but the boot code may also be stored in some other type of memory directly accessible to the CPU), but it's executed by the CPU, not the SSD (as your diagram seems to imply). The CPU would typically then instruct the SSD to supply it with its (File System) contents to be able to load the Operating System into its RAM. Many devices have their entire OS stored in boot (flash) ROM and do not need to load it into RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A system does not necessarily need NOR flash in order to boot. One example is the RaspberryPi that has internal boot rom that basically only knows how to read from a sdcard. From the sdcard it reads the secondary boot code and so on.
   Using the term DDR4 is a specific type of memory. Being specific only serves to confuse - be it DDR3, sram or whatever does not change the basic function - which is simply RAM.
2. What is a SSD? Basically an array of NAND flash to build mass storage device. For the purposes of explanation, it makes little difference if it is nor,nand, v-nand or a real magnetic hard disk - it is simply a mass storage device.
3. A processor 'core' is essentially one processor. Basically a machine the fetches instructions and performs arithmetic and logical operations. Multiple core is simply a number of these that share the same memory system. You could think of it as a number of students in a dormitory that share a common bathroom.
4. The web page isn't required to be stored on a mass storage device - it could simply just live in ram.

To fix up your diagram -
NOR flash would point to the cpu
SSD does not talk directly to the DDR4 memory - it will go through the cpu, so remove that link.
nand flash/SSD as explained are basically the same thing. Mass storage would connect to the cpu.

To be more precise - NOR flash might be called 'boot code' and optional
nand/SSD called 'mass storage'
DDR4 called 'RAM'
whether the CPU has one core or a zillion, makes no difference to your diagram.

For purposes of comparison, my TV boots from a NOR flash chip which has the complete operating system (Linux) and filesystem. This gets copied into ram at startup.

My car's engine computer has a single chip microcontroller that has on chip NOR flash. There is no 'boot' sequence as such - it simply starts executing code from flash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.